# form with parameters not getting data fields

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having trouble with this form.
I am not getting data fields: start_publish and: end_publish.
Everyone else is ok.
What can happen?
I need some help to finish this.

Controller Upload erb

```
def create
@upload = Upload.new(upload_params)
@upload.key = Emission.find(params[:id]).key
@upload.upload_file = params[:file]
@upload.emission_id = params[:id]
end
   def upload_params
  #params.require(:upload).permit(:start_publish, :end_publish)
  params.require(:file).permit(:start_publish, :end_publish)
end
```

end

form upload erb

```
    <%= form_for(@upload, html: { multipart: true,  :id => 'my_form'}) do |f|  %>
  <% if @upload.errors.any? %>
    <div class="bs-component">
        <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                <h4 class="messages">Error!</h4>
                <ul>
                <% @upload.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li><%= message %></li>
                <% end %>
                </ul>
        </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="form-horizontal">
      <fieldset>
      <legend><%= @title_form %></legend>

        <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.hidden_field :id_emission, :value => @emission.id %>
        <%= f.label :start_publish, 'Inicio', :class => 'col-lg-2 control-label' %>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
        <%= f.text_field :start_publish, :class => 'form-control', :id => 'datetimepicker4'  %>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :end_publish, 'Fin', :class => 'col-lg-2 control-label' %>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
        <%= f.text_field :end_publish, :class => 'form-control', :id => 'datetimepicker5'  %>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
      <div class="dropzone dropzone-previews" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
        <div id="dropzone">
        <div class="dz-message">
           <span class="message-int">
              Arrastre los archivos desde su computador o haga click aquí .<br>
              <span class="note">Por favor seleccione los archivos.</span>
             <div class="fallback">
              <%= f.file_field :file, multiple: true %>
             </div>
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="dropzone-previews"></div> <!-- this is were the previews should be shown. -->
    </div>
   <%= f.submit 'Guardar', :class => 'btn btn-primary pull-right', :id => 'btn-submit' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY H:mm'
      });
        });
  $(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY H:mm'
      });
        });

    var urls = '<%= uploads_url() %>';

</script>
```

Comment: Your logs should have a list of the params after the form submit, have you taken a look at that yet?

Comment: Seems like your data should be in params[:upload]. Why did you commented it out? Check your server logs, you will see params structure there.

Comment: If used: instead of upload: file not receive the file